# Anybody know of any sources/papers on wild animals identifying birds by their calls/sounds?

Tags: zoology, behaviour

I'm doing a literature review about identifying birds, and was hoping to find some examples of animals being able to identify birds by sound (eg a mouse knowing the normal call of a sparrow is not the normal call of a sparrowhawk), but alas when I tried to search google for anything all I got was a bunch of pages showing humans how to identify bird noises, or apps to do the job for you, even making sure the word "animal" was included lead to the same results.

I vaguely remember watching a BBC show that had meerkats using a bird to alert them for dangers, but when I tried to find this online all I found were sources saying how it's actually a bird pretending to be a meerkat to score a free lunch, so if anyone knows any more about this I'd be grateful for any information.